# RadRails (Eclipse plug-in) not recognizing 1.9.1 ruby features

Tags: ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rubygems, radrails

I installed RadRails as a plugin to eclipse, and I set the interpreter to `C:\ruby`, the location of my ruby installation. I've also installed `RubyGems 1.3.5` via the ruby `setup.rb` script.

When I run the following, however, I get syntax errors in eclipse, although running works.

```
test = {
   raw: '1',
   symbols: '2'
}

p test
```

Furthermore, when I start eclipse, a prompt asks me to install a number of gems. When I continue, I receive a number of `unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end` errors. Has anyone run into this, and is there a viable solution?

Comment: I still have the issue, and can't find a solution. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've installed the latest version of RadRails, it seems as if 1.9 is not yet supported.

The quick and easy solution is to not use Eclipse and RadRails. Personally, the only Windows IDE I've been remotely pleased with is [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). If you're on a Mac, the choice is much simpler: [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).